# How do I calculate the effective growth rate in excel, with monthly deposits?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I want to calculate the effective growth rate on a regular investment, using Excel. Imagine the following scenario:

- I have an initial investment of £10,000
- I invest an additional £200/month for 5 years
- At the end of the period, the investment is worth £30,000

Through trial and error, I can use the FV formula to confirm that the effective interest rate is 8.359%, because `FV(8.359%/12,5*12,-200,-10000)` is £30,000.

But how do I calculate this automatically? I've tried playing around with the RATE formula, but it doesn't appear to be designed for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The RATE function works, you just have to convert output from per month to per year.

`=RATE(60,-200,-10000,30000,0)*12` gives `0.08358859179`.